# Constructing a recursive compare with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, validation, loops

This is an ugly one. I wish I wasn't having to ask this question, but the project is already built such that we are handling heavy loads of validations in the database. Essentially, I'm trying to build a function that will take two stacks of data, weave them together with an unknown batch of operations or comparators, and produce a long string.

Yes, that was phrased very poorly, so I'm going to give an example. I have a form that can have multiple iterations of itself. For some reason, the system wants to know if the entered start date on any of these forms is equal to the entered end date on any of these forms. Unfortunately, due to the way the system is designed, everything is stored as a string, so I have to format it as a date first, before I can compare. Below is pseudo code, so please don't correct me on my syntax

**Input data:**

```
'logFormValidation("to_date(#) == to_date(^)"
                  , formname.control1name, formname.control2name)'
```

Now, as I mentioned, there are multiple iterations of this form, and I need to loop build a fully recursive comparison (note: it may not always be typical boolean comparisons, it could be internally called functions as well, so .In or anything like that won't work.) In the end, I need to get it into a format like below so the validation parser can read it.

```
OR(to_date(formname.control1name.1) == to_date(formname.control2name.1)
   ,to_date(formname.control1name.2) == to_date(formname.control2name.1)
   ,to_date(formname.control1name.3) == to_date(formname.control2name.1)
   ,to_date(formname.control1name.1) == to_date(formname.control2name.2)
   :
   :
   ,to_date(formname.control1name.n) == to_date(formname.control2name.n))
```

Yeah, it's ugly...but given the way our validation parser works, I don't have much of a choice. Any input on how this might be accomplished? I'm hoping for something more efficient than a double recursive loop, but don't have any ideas beyond that

Okay, seeing as my question is apparently terribly unclear, I'm going to add some more info. I don't know what comparison I will be performing on the items, I'm just trying to reformat the data into something useable for ANY given function. If I were to do this outside the database, it'd look something like this. Note: Pseudocode. '#' is the place marker in a function for vals1, '^' is a place marker for vals2.

```
function dynamicRecursiveValidation(string functionStr, strArray vals1, strArray vals2){
  string finalFunction = "OR("
  foreach(i in vals1){
    foreach(j in vals2){
      finalFunction += functionStr.replace('#', i).replace('^', j) + ",";
    }
  }
  finalFunction.substring(0, finalFunction.length - 1); //to remove last comma
  finalFunction += ")";

  return finalFunction;
}
```

That is all I'm trying to accomplish. Take any given comparator and two arrays, and create a string that contains every possible combination. Given the substitution characters I listed above, below is a list of possible added operations

```
# > ^
to_date(#) == to_date(^)
someFunction(#, ^)
# * 2 - 3 <= ^ / 4
```

All I'm trying to do is produce the string that I will later execute, and I'm trying to do it without having to kill the server in a recursive loop

Comment: What inputs will you get? Wha sort of solution are you expecting? What exactly do you want from us (other than our sympathy for your plight?

Comment: I'm looking for a method to recursively loop through that mess without having to write a double loop. If I'm stuck with the double loop, then okay...but I'd like to try to find an alternative way to produce the 'result' from the 'input'.

Comment: @guildsbounty so u want to compare 2 lists of string dates in an Oracle function?

Comment: @guildsbounty - I know you think you're explaining yourself but you really aren't.  Your comment merely recasts your original question: what we need is details, that is *additional* information.

Comment: The problem is this...I don't have any more information. All I know is that I will be given two arrays, and an operation that I need to perform on them, and I have to write a single function to handle all of that at once. I gave that as a single example, but it could also be "Compare strings" "Execute this function and see if it returns true" and it would have to be run against each and every item in the array. I'm not trying to run a compare, I'm trying to reformat...I'll edit the question to show what I'd do with it pseudo-code if I could work outside the DB

Comment: @guildsbounty If the comparison function runs inside the DB it's much easier to simply call a predefined function with arrays that would do the comparison.  You are trying to rewrite the stuff you receive into a condition that would receive true or false, instead rewrite it into a function call.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have that option...this is really the only way I can do it, on account of how varied the calls can be, and how the system already works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up performing a cross product of the data, and looping through the results. It wasn't the sort of solution I really wanted, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution code for this but you can algorithmically do the following

1. Create a temp table `(start_date, end_date, formid)` and populate it with every date from any existing form
2. Get the start_date from the form and simply:

   `SELECT end_date, form_id FROM temp_table WHERE end_date = <start date to check>`
3. For the reverse

   `SELECT start_date, form_id FROM temp_table WHERE start_date = <end date to check>`

If the database is available why not let it do all the heavy lifting.